# How to generate documentation from Django models?

Tags: python, django

At the moment we use [Sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/) for project documentation and Django models field description.

The main problem is that: after changing models, we manually updated Sphinx docs and sometimes forget/miss some fields in docs.

Is there some tool for generate docs based on Django models?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to generate docs for Django - use **admindocs** [app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/).

Comment: How can I generate an all inclusive PDF containing all the pages of that `/admin/doc/`?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/admindocs/

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/internals/contributing/writing-documentation/#getting-started-with-sphinx) says:

> Django’s documentation uses the Sphinx documentation system, which in
> turn is based on docutils. The basic idea is that lightly-formatted
> plain-text documentation is transformed into HTML, PDF, and any other
> output format.

So you should just use sphinx to generate the doc for your django application. You should activate pulling documentation from docstrings in sphinx using the autodoc extension, to activate put this in your `conf.py` for sphinx:

```
extensions = [
    'sphinx.ext.autodoc',
]
```

Comment: it is possible to generate fields docs based on `verbose_name`?

Comment: @A.Innokentiev isn't that the default? I haven't used sphinx, but I have seen som very nice standard Django behaviour related to `verbose_name` or (maybe closer to what you expect) `help_text`.

Comment: @MariusSiuram I'm looking for tool, that can generate docs (for frontend developers) based on Django models. I want some features as this: if we add/remove some models fields or editing `verbose_name` - docs automatically updated.